# Making a 7x7 checkboard in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I run the code below nothing shows up on my webpage and I'm wondering why.

I'm not too sure what i'm doing wrong here. I tried running this through ChatGPT and it said it should work but when I run it the page is left completely blank.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 49; i++) {
  const createDivs = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(createDivs);
  if (i % 2 === 0) {
    createDivs.classList.add('set-to-black');
  } else {
    createDivs.classList.add('set-to-red');
  }
}

const setToBlack = document.getElementsByClassName('set-to-black');

for (let i = 0; i < setToBlack.length; i++) {
  setToBlack[i].style.backgroundColor = 'black';
  setToBlack[i].style.height = '60px';
};

const setToRed = document.getElementsByClassName('set-to-red');

for (let i = 0; i < setToRed.length; i++) {
  setToRed[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
   setToRed[i].style.height = '60px';
};
```

Comment: So open up your developer tools in the browser and check to see if there are any error messages. And do you really have the entire script block commented out like you do above??

Comment: You add a class, why are you not setting the colors and sizes in the CSS? It would eliminate your two loops

Comment: I removed the comments and your code generates red and black divs....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncomment your code, remove the lines that sets the height then add just a tiny bit of CSS and you're there. Fully annotated example below.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 49; i++) {
  const createDivs = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(createDivs);
  if (i % 2 === 0) {
    createDivs.classList.add('set-to-black');
  } else {
    createDivs.classList.add('set-to-red');
  }
}

const setToBlack = document.getElementsByClassName('set-to-black');
for (let i = 0; i < setToBlack.length; i++) {
  setToBlack[i].style.backgroundColor = 'black';
  /*setToBlack[i].style.height = '60px'; removed this so the divs are square */
};

const setToRed = document.getElementsByClassName('set-to-red');
for (let i = 0; i < setToRed.length; i++) {
  setToRed[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
   /*setToRed[i].style.height = '60px'; removed this so the divs are square*/
};
```

```css
div {
  width: calc(100% / 7); /* make each div 1/7th of the overall width so the 8th, 16th, etc start on a new linw */
  display: inline-block; /* make them behave like inline block elements so siblings elements sit next to each other */
  vertical-align: top; /* this removes the space for descenders */
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1; /* make them all square */
}
```

Comment: Thank you I was just trying my best not to use CSS lol.

Comment: And yeah i knew to uncomment the code but I was just trying different methods

Comment: You're very welcome! CSS is the way to go imho! (from a die-hard css fan haha)

Answer (score 0):

Using [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) you can solve this with one loop.

1. Set a container.
2. Create some CSS using CSS Grid, and using `nth-child` to identify which square should be black/red.
3. Create some HTML identifying each square with a `square` class, and adding in a colour class depending on whether the iteration index is odd or even.
4. Finally add the HTML to the container element.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const html = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 49; i++) {
  const color = i % 2 === 0 ? 'red' : 'black';
  html.push(`<div class="square ${color}"></div>`);
}

container.innerHTML = html.join('');
```

```css
.container { display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(7, calc(100% / 7)); width: 100%; }
.square { calc(100% / 7); aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;}
.square:nth-child(odd) { background-color: black; }
.square:nth-child(even) { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<section class="container"></section>
```

Additional documentation

- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)